# TypeScript `tsc` not picking up tsconfig.json inside a subdirectory?

Tags: typescript

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── tsconfig.json ("module": "CommonJS")
└── foo/
    ├── node-file.ts
    └── bar/
        ├── browser-file.ts
        └── tsconfig.json ("module": "esnext")
```

The root `tsconfig.json` has `module` set to `CommonJS` because I want most of my files to compile for Node. But inside `bar`,  I want the files to compile to JavaScript Modules, so I've set `module` to `esnext`.

Now when I run `tsc` from the root, I expect `node-file.ts` to compile to `CommonJS` module and `browser-file.ts` to compile to a JavaScript Module. But that's not what I'm getting. It seems that `tsc` is completely ignoring `foo/bar/tsconfig.json` and is only picking up the root `tsconfig.json`.

(I also use `tsc --watch` while developing, so I'm trying to avoid having to run two different `tsc` processes to compile the two different targets. It feels to me that running a single `tsc` with nested `tsconfig.json` files should give me the desired results.)

Anyone know what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: TypeScript only uses one `tsconfig.json` and doesn't automatically use subdirectories' `tsconfig.json` for the files there. You may want to look into [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html)

Comment: I couldn’t tell if project references will allow me to set a different module type per directory, I’ll look more into it. But thanks for correcting my wrong assumption about how the compiler works. Feel free to post this as an answer and I’ll accept it.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is implemented by IDEs like VS Code. The fact that `tsc` doesn't support this beahviour means that we can't easily type-check our codebases in a way that reports the exact same errors as our IDEs by default. This is sooo annoying and makes setting up monorepo projects unnecessarily challenging. The "simplest" workaround is to create additional `tsconfig.<something>.json` files that include only the files that are not included by nested `tsconfig` files and then run `tsc -p` for each of them...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

TypeScript only uses one `tsconfig.json` and doesn’t automatically use subdirectories’ `tsconfig.json` for the files there. However, you can use [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) for this.

Create a directory structure like this:

```
.
├── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.settings.json (optional)
└── foo/
    ├── node-file.ts
    ├── tsconfig.json ("module": "commonjs")
    └── bar/
        ├── browser-file.ts
        └── tsconfig.json ("module": "esnext")
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {"path": "./foo"},
    {"path": "./foo/bar"}
  ]
}
```

This is the root `tsconfig.json`. When you run `tsc --build` (see below) in the root directory, TypeScript will build the referenced projects `./foo/tsconfig.json` and `./foo/bar/tsconfig.json`.

The `"files": []` is to stop accidental `tsc`s without `--build` from attempting to compile everything in the root directory, which will error but create multiple `.js` files in possibly the incorrect places.

`tsconfig.settings.json` (optional)

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true
  }
}
```

You can put configuration common to `foo` and `foo/bar` and extend this configuration with [`extends`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends) to reduce duplication. Note that all relative paths in here will be resolved relative to `tsconfig.settings.json` when extended, so something like `"outDir": "dist"` may not work as expected.

`foo/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.settings.json",
  "exclude": ["bar/**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

This is the configuration for the CommonJS files. It also extends the common config and excludes the files in `foo/bar`.

`foo/bar/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.settings.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

This is pretty similar to `foo`’s configuration.

---

### Building

To compile `foo` and `foo/bar` at the same time, use build mode from the root directory:

```bash
tsc --build         # or tsc -b
# Watch mode:
tsc --build --watch # or tsc -bw
```

From [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#build-mode-for-typescript):

> A long-awaited feature is smart incremental builds for TypeScript projects. In 3.0 you can use the `--build` flag with `tsc`. This is effectively a new entry point for `tsc` that behaves more like a build orchestrator than a simple compiler.
>
> Running `tsc --build` (`tsc -b` for short) will do the following:
>
> - Find all referenced projects
> - Detect if they are up-to-date
> - Build out-of-date projects in the correct order
>
> You can provide `tsc -b` with multiple config file paths (e.g. `tsc -b src test`). Just like `tsc -p`, specifying the config file name itself is unnecessary if it’s named `tsconfig.json`.

You can also compile individual projects:

```bash
tsc -b foo     # or cd foo     && tsc -b
tsc -b foo/bar # or cd foo/bar && tsc -b
```

Note that are some build-only flags and [you cannot override compiler options with command-line arguments](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25613).

Comment: What if something inside the subfolder (bar) access a function exposed by the upper folder foo?

Comment: @igol You should be able to add a reference to the foo project from bar with `"references": [{"path": "../foo"}]` in bar’s tsconfig.